# Bash: keep some commands in history for current session only

Tags: bash, command-history

My HISTIGNORE var:

`export HISTIGNORE="&:[bf]g:exit:mc:htop:top:clear:reset:histoty *:df *:du *:kill *:pkill *:pushd *:popd:bash *:yaourt *:pacman *:upd"`

All what i want is to keep these commands in history for current bash session and to ignore them in subsequent sessions. Other commands (not in the HISTIGNORE) should be in .bash_history file.
Example (pushd in $HISTIGNORE, cd not)

`pushd /home/

(Ctrl-R)push(Enter) -> pushd /home

cd /usr/src

bash

(Ctrl-R)push(Enter) -> (Anything but pushd)

(Ctrl-R)cd(Enter) ->  cd /usr/src`

Is there any solutions for these problem?

Comment: While this question doesn't belong here, I'll suggest setting export HISTFILESIZE=0 to get the session-only effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to just set the `HISTIGNORE` to nothing for the current session at the beginning,

`export HISTIGNORE=""`

and then set it back again for other session by adding it to `.bashrc`file